# Errors when migrating heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Im attempting to rake my migrations on my heroku distro.  im getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "plants" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "images" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_d5e1aedcb5"
FOREIGN KEY ("plant_id")
REFERENCES "plants" ("id")
```

Some of my tables go through, but not this one, im not sure what is even going on here.  It works in development, but not in production.

Here is my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160521081000) do

  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "task"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "cycles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.boolean  "completed"
    t.integer  "tray_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "due_date"
  end

  add_index "cycles", ["tray_id"], name: "index_cycles_on_tray_id"

  create_table "datalogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tray_id"
    t.float    "ambcur"
    t.float    "ambmin"
    t.float    "ambmax"
    t.float    "folcur"
    t.float    "folmin"
    t.float    "folmax"
    t.float    "ph"
    t.float    "heatmat"
    t.float    "h202"
    t.float    "tds"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "datalogs", ["tray_id"], name: "index_datalogs_on_tray_id"

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "grows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "file_id"
    t.integer  "plant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "tray_id"
  end

  add_index "images", ["plant_id"], name: "index_images_on_plant_id"

  create_table "nutrient_calcs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "product"
    t.integer  "vegtime"
    t.integer  "flowertime"
    t.float    "rezsize"
    t.string   "rezunits"
    t.boolean  "aerstone"
    t.string   "outputunits"
    t.integer  "nutrient_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "nutrient_calcs", ["nutrient_id"], name: "index_nutrient_calcs_on_nutrient_id"

  create_table "nutrients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "manufacturer"
    t.float    "price"
    t.string   "unit"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "plant_cycles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "interval"
    t.integer  "frequency"
    t.integer  "plant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "plant_cycles", ["plant_id"], name: "index_plant_cycles_on_plant_id"

  create_table "plantdats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float    "ambtemp"
    t.float    "foltempcur"
    t.float    "foltempmin"
    t.float    "foltempmax"
    t.float    "ph"
    t.float    "heatmat"
    t.integer  "tds"
    t.float    "h202"
    t.integer  "plant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float    "ambtempmin"
    t.float    "ambtembmax"
  end

  add_index "plantdats", ["plant_id"], name: "index_plantdats_on_plant_id"

  create_table "plants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "species"
    t.integer  "tray_id"
    t.integer  "species_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "plants", ["category_id"], name: "index_plants_on_category_id"
  add_index "plants", ["tray_id"], name: "index_plants_on_tray_id"
  add_index "plants", ["user_id"], name: "index_plants_on_user_id"

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "schedulable_id"
    t.string   "schedulable_type"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.string   "rule"
    t.string   "interval"
    t.text     "day"
    t.text     "day_of_week"
    t.datetime "until"
    t.integer  "count"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "species", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "plant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "species", ["plant_id"], name: "index_species_on_plant_id"

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "plant_id"
    t.integer  "tray_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "due_date"
  end

  add_index "tasks", ["plant_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_plant_id"
  add_index "tasks", ["tray_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_tray_id"

  create_table "tray_cycles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "tray_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "tray_cycles", ["tray_id"], name: "index_tray_cycles_on_tray_id"

  create_table "trays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "rescap"
  end

  add_index "trays", ["category_id"], name: "index_trays_on_category_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Also, my app gets pushed to Heroku, but when I go to 'sign_up', I get the error from the heroku logs:

```
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678059+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `firstname' for #<User:0x007fa667e33798>):
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678049+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678060+00:00 app[web.1]:     25: 
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678061+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:           <div class="field">
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678062+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:             <%= f.label 'First Name' %><br />
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678063+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:             <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, rows: 10, cols: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'ENTER FIRST NAME' %>
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678064+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:           </div>
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678065+00:00 app[web.1]:     30: 
2016-05-22T07:53:31.678065+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:           <div class="field">
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?  Many thanks :)

Comment: I'm assuming that the table plants does not exist at the time you're trying to use it as a foreign key in the table images. Can you confirm that it does (does an earlier migration add the tables plants than the migration that adds the foreign key to images ?)

Comment: @xyious Im looking through my migrations folder and dont see one that adds plants. but it is in the schema.  not even sure whats up with that

Comment: Is it possible that the migration file got deleted after the plants table was created ? Do you have source control ? can you check ?

Comment: @xyious I suppose it is possible, but i dont remember deleting it.  Do i just create a new migration to fix this?

Comment: I would honestly suggest just ignoring migrations and possibly even throwing away the whole folder. set up the db layout with "rake db:schema:load". Which should, in theory, set up a database layout that's exactly the same as you have now on your system.

Comment: yes, that worked just fine actually.  Thanks for helping me out.  I would have stumbled upon this eventually, Ive just been coding the last 16 hours.  Thanks for helping, now i can get some sleep.  Cheers :)

Comment: I dont know why there are 2 downvotes . And I strongly believe if someone down voting a questions / answer they should add a small comment on why they do that ..

Answer (score 2):

Apparently one of the migration files got lost.
If the migration directory is quite full, or not consistent with the database you can use `rake db:schema:load` to directly create the whole DB.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @xyious in the comments.  Somehow a few migrations got deleted unbeknownst to me.  Running `heroku run rake db:schema:load`
fixed the problem.